# Pygame's Group.remove() function slows down game

Tags: python, pygame, pygame-surface

In the space invaders project in Python Crash Course, we need to remove the bullets from the group once they are out of the bounds of the screen. This is achieved by

```
for bullet in self.bullets.copy():
    if bullet.rect.bottom <= 0:
        self.bullets.remove(bullet)
```

After saving and running the program as it is, the game seemed to have slowed down considerably to the point where it was unplayable. I changed the speed of the bullet, but the game became stuttery and laggy.
The structure of the game where the remove function is present is somewhat like this:

```
while True: # main game loop
    --snip--
    self.game_updates() # other game functions
    self._update_bullets() # updating the bullets
    --snip--
```

```
def _update_bullets():
    self.bullets.update() # updates the rect.y of the bullets. self.bullets is the Group.
    for bullet in self.bullets.copy():
        if bullet.rect.bottom <= 0:
            self.bullets.remove(bullet)
```

I am sure it is not the if statement or the loop structure which is slowing it down, rather it is the remove() function. I tried replacing the remove with a print statement, and it works without any lag.

How can this be fixed?

(If you wish to view the entire project, [here](https://easyupload.io/ag0ji1) is the link.)

Comment: I just tried your version of the game, with the `remove()` call active, and it does not lag at all on my system. Does using `kill()` as mentioned below fix the issue for you?

Comment: @japhyr yes it did, to a great extent.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`self.bullets` is a [`pygame.sprite.Group()`](https://www.pygame.org/docs/ref/sprite.html#pygame.sprite.Group) object. If you want to remove [`pygame.sprites.Sprite`](https://www.pygame.org/docs/ref/sprite.html#pygame.sprite.Sprite) objects you have to call [`kill`](https://www.pygame.org/docs/ref/sprite.html#pygame.sprite.Sprite.kill):

> remove the Sprite from all Groups

```py
for bullet in self.bullets:
    if bullet.rect.bottom <= 0:
        bullet.kill()
```

With this solution you do not need to `copy` the `pygame.sprite.Group`.